# Spring Boot Configuration Properties Null in Another Application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I have two spring boot applications.

Application 01 includes custom-data.yml. I have successfully loaded the data from custom-data.yml in application 01 via @Propertysource. Application 01 is packed as jar file.

I put application 01 as dependency in application 02. I tried to load custom-data.yml in application 02. But I have failed to load.

May I know how shall I load the data without adding any yml in application 02?

## Update

After exploring quite a bit, there are two ways to solve this problem.

One way is to rename application-customdata.yml and include "customdata" in spring profile of application 02.

Another way is to use properties file. Just create custom-data.properties file and read from it.